# NUL characters appear at the end of some files sometimes

Tags: filesystems, sync, nas, visual-studio-code, synology

Since I am using [Synology](https://www.synology.com/de-de/dsm/feature/drive) to backup my files and sync them between devices, I sometimes get `NUL` characters at the end of my files and sometimes 2 or 3 lines are deleted randomly at the end of the file.

I don't know if it happens everywhere or just in VS Code, but I think it only happens in VS Code, because I didn't notice that behaviour in any other app.
What can I do to prevent this from happening?

I am using Windows and WSL2 and sometimes Ubuntu (Dual Boot).

[image]

Comment: This [post](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/1332) says it is a problem when using SMB on a Mac to mount a Linux file system. Is this your case?

Comment: Could be the same problem, yes. Thank you for sharing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2016 post
[NUL characters added when saving on an SMB mount on a Mac #1332](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/1332)
may discuss the same problem.

Although the post is about Sublime Text, the conclusion was that this is an operating system bug. It sometimes only happens with a specific text-editor and not with others, perhaps triggered by the editor using some particular actions.

The workarounds in the post were :

- Try another text-editor
- Avoid SMB, for example by switching to NFS.